# Fonts look Blurry in Safari

Tags: fonts, safari

In my site, the fonts work well in all major browsers from localhost including safari, but when I've uploaded it to server it behaves differently(blur) in safari. In css:

```css
@font-face{
    font-family:'NotoSansMalayalam-Regular';
    src: url('font/NotoSansMalayalam-Regular.ttf')format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.font{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:normal}
.font-m{font-family:'NotoSansMalayalam-Regular'; }
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong please anyone can help me?

Comment: Try `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

Comment: it works..thank u @claudios

Comment: Added an answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work in different browsers add just vendor prefixes.

To solve your issue you can use:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

For additional info you can head over to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=font-smoothing).